# How to use your voice to add items to a shopping list?

Tags: google-now, to-do-list, s-voice

With iOS Siri, you can say "Add tomatoes to my shopping list" and it will add it to a list titled "Shopping List" in the "Notes" app, easy.

In Android, using S Voice or Google Voice, if you say "Add tomatoes to my shopping list" it will google that, which is unhelpful.

Ideally there should be a way to add items to lists generically in Google Now. Is there such a workflow?

I am aware Grocery IQ app has Voice entry, but then the workflow is tedious: Hold a button, say OK google, say Open Grocery IQ, then tap a mic, then Say tomatoes.

Comment: You might want to look into Google Keep. I'm not sure of its complete voice-commandability, but it might prove helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now say "Ok Google" followed by "Add Chicken to my Shopping List" via Google voice recognition app. See a [list of Google now voice commands](http://technorelease.com/google-voice-commands/) here.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use notes on the front home screen that is easy-access.

[image: Ala]